# Ifstream segmentation fault

Tags: c++, file

I have a string named `actions` with multiple file names, spaces, and line breaks between those file names, like this:

```
File1 File2 File3 File4
File5 File6 File7 File8
```

I want to open the files one by one, so I am splitting the string by spaces to get the file names individually.

```
std::stringstream ss(actions);
std::string newline;

while(std::getline(ss, newline, '\n')){
    std::stringstream s1(newline);
    std::string espacos;
    std::getline(s1,espacos,' ');
    char* file = &espacos[0u];
    cout << file << '\n';
    ifstream ficheiro;
    ficheiro.open(file);
    ....
}
```

This is where I am splitting.

The string `espacos` is the one which will iterate through the newline by getting the file names one by one.

I am converting from `string` to `char*` but in the end I get a segmentation fault.

I used a debugger and it said that this line was causing the segmentation fault:

```
ficheiro.open(file);
```

So I print `char* file` to check if everything is ok, and I get this output:

```
File1
File2
File3
File4
```

Since everything is ok with the file name, and I can open every file but `File4`, what do you think is causing this error?

PS: I am closing the file after every loop.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: That code only gets the first name on each line. There must be something crucial missing.

Comment: I forgot the loop in which it gets every name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see the code shown to segfault is if `file` is not pointing at a valid null-terminated C-style string.

That could happen if:

- your STL's implementation of `std::string` does not use a sequential memory block to hold the individual characters.
- your STL's implementation of `std::string` does use a sequential memory block, but does not null-terminate that memory block.

Either way would cause `&espacos[0u]` to produce a pointer that is not a valid null-terminated C-style string.  Most STL implementations do use a sequential null-terminated memory block (as it simplifies the implementation), but that is not guaranteed until C++11, which enforces such an implementation.

In any case, you shouldn't be using `&espacos[0u]` to begin with. You should be using `espacos.c_str()` instead, which is guaranteed in all C++ versions to return a pointer to a null-terminated C-style string:

```
const char* file = espacos.c_str();
```

That being said, `operator>>` splits a stream on spaces and line breaks by default, so you can greatly simplify the code to this:

```
std::istringstream iss(actions);
std::string espacos;

while (iss >> espacos) {
    cout << espacos << '\n';
    ifstream ficheiro(espacos.c_str());
    // or, in C++11 and later:
    // ifstream ficheiro(espacos);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I found out what the problem was and i am using OpenGl with VBO's and the problem was with that vbo, but i want to thank you because of the tips you gave.